# Subgit: exclude old tags by name

Tags: subgit

I'd like to ignore old tags during the translation process. I'm trying to use

```
excludeBranches = tags/Server_*_2007-*
```

to match tag names like `Server_423_2007-02-28_11-40', but subgit complains about using multiple * symbols.

How can I ignore old tags (based on year in the tag name) during translation? We have a lot of these tags, one for each build, and it slows down import a lot (I think). I want to keep most recent ones (from 2015, 2016) only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 3.2.0 of SubGit you can use multiple asterisks in 'excludeBranches' option.